# unknown display in display settings fedora

Tags: fedora, xrandr, intel-graphics, display-settings

i'm new in fedora and i wanna use two duplicate displays but i see no option in display settings.
[image]

Well, I see same things on the both screens and **'Unknown Display'** in display settings, which means I:

- cannot add a second/third/etc screen,
- cannot adjust the resolution,

when i was searching my issue found that there is some bug with some VGAs that related with my problem. i managed to find some solution but all of them were useful for Ubuntu.

### Some potentially interesting stats:

- `lspci | grep VGA` output:

> ```
> [bayat@b-fedora-taraz-com ~]$ lspci | grep VGA
> 00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 8th Gen Core Processor Gaussian Mixture Model
> ```

---

- `xrandr` output:

> ```
>    [bayat@b-fedora-taraz-com ~]$ xrandr 
>     xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
>     Screen 0: minimum 1024 x 768, current 1024 x 768, maximum 1024 x 768
>     default connected primary 1024x768+0+0 0mm x 0mm
>        1024x768       0.00*
> ```

### Here are some specifics about my system:

- I am running Fedora 31.
- Processor: Intel® Core™ i3-8100 CPU @ 3.60GHz × 4.
- Graphics: llvmpipe (LLVM 9.0, 256 bits).
- GNOME Version 3.34.8

If any additional info is needed to figure out what's going on, please let me know. And thanks in advance for any help on this

Comment: What is the monitor? Are both the primary and the duplicate one the same?

Comment: no their not the same. one Samsung, one hp. when i use only one of them still the same problem exists (i have no options in display settings).

Comment: That's very odd. I think my next step would be to boot a Fedora 33 live CD — or just update to Fedora 33 — to see if that resolves the issue.

Comment: thanks for your help dude @mattdm